# How to convert these 4 mini tables from vertical to 2 x 2 frame?

Tags: tables

I like to convert the following four tables in 2 x2 format instead of displaying them vertically. Also the figure environment is labeling them as fig which is not desired as I want to label them as table. Please help.

```
\documentclass[final,1p,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{Accuracy calculations under different classifiers}
    
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Decision Tree}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Identity & Precision & Recall & f1-score & Support \\
            \hline
             User1 & 0.99 & 0.99 & 0.99 & 12889 \\
            \hline% Add data rows here
            User2& 0.99 & 0.99 & 0.99 &23646 \\
            \hline
            User3 & 0.99 & 0.99 & 0.99 &12076 \\
            \hline
            User4&0.99 & 0.99 & 0.99 &11345 \\
            \hline
            User5& 0.99 & 0.99 & 0.99 &10765 \\
            \hline
            User6& 0.99 & 0.99 & 0.99 &10244 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \vspace{1em}
    
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{KNN}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Identity & Precision & Recall & f1-score & Support \\
            \hline
            User1&0.89 &0.95 &0.93 &12889 \\
            \hline
            User2&0.85 &0.88 & 0.87 &23646 \\
            \hline
            User3& 0.93&0.98 &0.95 & 12076\\
            \hline
            User4& 0.89& 0.78 &0.84 &  11345 \\
            \hline
            User5&0.91 & 0.88 &0.90 &10765 \\
            \hline
            User6&0.87 &0.82 &0.85 &10244 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \vspace{1em}
    
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{SVM}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Identity & Precision & Recall & f1-score & Support \\
            \hline
            User1&0.82&0.88&0.85 &12889 \\
            \hline
            User2&0.68 &0.70 & 0.70&23646 \\
            \hline
            User3& 0.81&0.95 &0.87 & 12076\\
            \hline
            User4& 0.72& 0.59 &0.65 &  11345 \\
            \hline
            User5&0.77 & 0.72 &0.75&10765 \\
            \hline
            User6&0.62 &0.56 &0.59 &10244 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subfigure}
     \vspace{1em}
    
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Logistic Regression}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Identity & Precision & Recall & f1-score & Support \\
            \hline
            User1&0.62 & 0.73 &0.67&12889 \\
            \hline
            User2& 0.45 & 0.46 & 0.45 &23646 \\
            \hline
            User3& 0.70&0.79 & 0.74 & 12076\\
            \hline
            User4& 0.54& 0.46 &0.50 &  11345 \\
            \hline
            User5&0.63 & 0.64 &0.64 &10765 \\
            \hline
            User6&0.46 &0.33 &0.39&10244 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

The desired output is something like
[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

Some of the main changes, relative to the OP's sample code:

- change all four instances of `subfigure` to `subtable` and the instance of `figure` to `table`
- change all four instances of `{\textwidth}` to `{0.475\textwidth}`
- use abbreviations in header cells (to allow the columns to become narrower)
- reduce the value of `\tabcolsep` (affects the amount of whitespace padding)
- switch to `\small` relative font size (for a 10% linear reduction in font size)
- eliminate blank lines between subtables a/b and c/d, resp., as blank lines cause line breaks
- change `\vspace{1em}` between subtables a/b and c/d to `\hfill`

---

```
\documentclass[final,1p,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{array,subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default value: 6pt
\caption{Accuracy calculations under different classifiers}

    \begin{subtable}{0.475\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Decision Tree}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Ident. & Prec. & Recall & f1-sc. & Supp. \\
            \hline
            User1 & 0.99 & 0.99 & 0.99 & 12889 \\
            \hline% Add data rows here
            User2& 0.99 & 0.99 & 0.99 &23646 \\
            \hline
            User3 & 0.99 & 0.99 & 0.99 &12076 \\
            \hline
            User4&0.99 & 0.99 & 0.99 &11345 \\
            \hline
            User5& 0.99 & 0.99 & 0.99 &10765 \\
            \hline
            User6& 0.99 & 0.99 & 0.99 &10244 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subtable}{0.475\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{KNN}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Ident. & Prec. & Recall & f1-sc. & Supp. \\
            \hline
            User1&0.89 &0.95 &0.93 &12889 \\
            \hline
            User2&0.85 &0.88 & 0.87 &23646 \\
            \hline
            User3& 0.93&0.98 &0.95 & 12076\\
            \hline
            User4& 0.89& 0.78 &0.84 &  11345 \\
            \hline
            User5&0.91 & 0.88 &0.90 &10765 \\
            \hline
            User6&0.87 &0.82 &0.85 &10244 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}

    \vspace{2ex}

    \begin{subtable}{0.475\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{SVM}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Ident. & Prec. & Recall & f1-sc. & Supp. \\
            \hline
            User1&0.82&0.88&0.85 &12889 \\
            \hline
            User2&0.68 &0.70 & 0.70&23646 \\
            \hline
            User3& 0.81&0.95 &0.87 & 12076\\
            \hline
            User4& 0.72& 0.59 &0.65 &  11345 \\
            \hline
            User5&0.77 & 0.72 &0.75&10765 \\
            \hline
            User6&0.62 &0.56 &0.59 &10244 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subtable}{0.475\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Logistic Regression}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Ident. & Prec. & Recall & f1-sc. & Supp. \\
            \hline
            User1&0.62 & 0.73 &0.67&12889 \\
            \hline
            User2& 0.45 & 0.46 & 0.45 &23646 \\
            \hline
            User3& 0.70&0.79 & 0.74 & 12076\\
            \hline
            User4& 0.54& 0.46 &0.50 &  11345 \\
            \hline
            User5&0.63 & 0.64 &0.64 &10765 \\
            \hline
            User6&0.46 &0.33 &0.39&10244 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}
    
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The output is as desired, but it is still labelled as figure. As mentioned in OP, this should overall be labelled as table. As a partial solution, I am upvoting the proposed answer. If it can be changed to table overall (Something like a 2 x 2 table whose cells hold the mini tables), it can be accepted as final answer. Thank you Mico.

Comment: @Bukaida -- Ah, I had overlooked this point. It's easily fixed by changing all instances of `subfigure` to `subtable` and all instances of `figure` to `table`.  Will do so now.

Comment: Thanks, the answer is complete now. BTW, wouldn't it end with \end{table} instead of \end{figure} ?

Comment: @Bukaida - Good catch -- fixed now. (It was fixed in the code on my computer that generated the screenshot, but I had evidently failed to fully update the code shown above.)

Comment: Student is not picking up bad, huh? LOL